# What does SAGA stand for in optimization solvers?

Tags: optimization, statistics, data-science

If SAG stands for *Stochastic Average Gradient* what does SAGA stand for?

From Sklearn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

From lightning (http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/lightning/)

Answer (score 2):

SAGA stands for Stochastic Average Gradient Accelerated Method.
Reference: [https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneDAL/daal/algorithms/optimization-solvers/solvers/stochastic-average-gradient-accelerated-method.html#:~:text=The%20Stochastic%20Average%20Gradient%20Accelerated,the%20batch%20size%20b%3D1](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneDAL/daal/algorithms/optimization-solvers/solvers/stochastic-average-gradient-accelerated-method.html#:%7E:text=The%20Stochastic%20Average%20Gradient%20Accelerated,the%20batch%20size%20b%3D1).